# Changing Variant for a particular product from Swatch to Drop down

Tags: shopify, product, variant

Wanted to know is it possible to change the variant from Swatch to Dropdown in Shopify for a particular product.

There is an option in the theme setting but it changes for all the products.

Thank you for your help

[image: Variant Title/Option Title]
[image]

Comment: you need to check  code and add `{% if %}` for a product based on id of product.

Comment: Little harder of suggest the code, because there is no other details regarding the code and product

Comment: Thank you for your comment was able to do based on this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68141842/how-to-get-separate-drop-down-for-color-and-size-on-collection-page-in-shopify

Now I'm stuck with the Option Variant name. Its not being displayed.

Comment: @Onkar Based on the above link  here is the code

{% for option in product.options_with_values %}          
   <select  class="option-selector {{option.name}}" data-var="{{forloop.index}}">             
   {% if product.available %}              
            {% for values in option.values %}
         <option value ="{{option.name}}">{{values}}</option>
     
      {% endfor %} 

The code does not display the variant name/title.

Is there a way to display the Variant/option name/title. (Eg: Size, Color, )

Comment: Are you sure the product is available? means have quantity

Comment: code seems good, you need to check it on product level, for share the URL of product to check it.

Comment: @Onkar Yes, the product is available. The Dropdown is also be displayed. Its just that the header is not showing (Size, Color, Flavour)

Comment: @Onkar I have added the images in the question

Comment: To add this type of heading you need to edit the code, It create only the select elements for now.

Comment: @Onkar Ok. I was searching for it online there are different solutions but was not able to find a solution that works

Is the below code somewhat that will work

{% for variant in p_variants %}
    {{ variant.title }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

Comment: @Onkar I was able to figure out to add the Variant title. Thank you for your comment and help.